# unable to escape space in command shell of Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, escaping, command, command-line-arguments

If I execute

`cmd /c "%programfiles%\mycode\md5sums.exe" %temp%`

it works just fine. But when I execute

`cmd /c "%programfiles%\mycode\md5sums.exe" %programfiles%`

I get below error-

`Error: Unable to read file/directory C:\Program`

which means that md5sums.exe is trying to open `C:\Program` as opposed to full path given by %programfiles%

I've to use `cmd /c` as I've to run this command remotely.

How do I make it work? 
I've tried using  `"%programfiles%" but in this case even md5sums.exe is not getting executed.

Eventually I would like to use switch "/b" provided by md5sums.exe but at this point of time I am stuck at even making md5sums run on %programfiles%

Comment: I just made it work by using 

`"cmd /c "%programfiles%\mycode\md5sums.exe" %programfiles%"`

now.. I am stuck at how to apply `/b` switch to md5sums.exe?

Comment: sorry... I meant how do I add `-b` switch?

Comment: Add it as another argument between the two existing arguments to `/c`, e.g. `cmd /c "md5sum" "-b" "%programfiles%"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
cmd /c "%programfiles%\mycode\md5sums.exe" "%programfiles%"
                                           ^--------------^--quotes added
```

Otherwise, you end up with something like:

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\mycode\md5sums.exe" C:\Program Files
```

and end up passing two arguments to md5sums, not a single path.

Answer (score 1):

you need a double double quote at start and end 
e.g.:

`cmd /c ""%programfiles%\mycode\md5sums.exe" "%programfiles%""`